# Increasing hover area of CSS circle

Tags: html, css

I have a page with little elements with border-radius set to 50%, so they show up as little dots:

[image: Said dots look like this]

CSS:

```
.star {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(1);
    display: block;
    transition: 0.25s ease-in background-color, 0.25s ease-in opacity, 0.25s ease-out transform;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Each of these has a hover action that brings up a certain pop-up. Now however, there's an issue where hovering (at least in the browsers I've tested for) is a game of find the pixel.

Is there a "trick" to add an invisible border or so to the dots to make them more selectable without hunting for pixels?

Setting `border` to say `2px solid transparent` just makes the circles bigger in my tests, and CSS `outline` does not produce a `:hover` state or `mouseenter` event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.star {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#000;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-clip:content-box; /* <- key point*/
}   

.star:hover { background-color:#f00; }
```

```html
<div class="star"></div>
```

Increased padding will give you larger hit margins.

Comment: Good answer ! To be noted that the background-clip property will also solve the issue on OP original intent (adding a transparent border, instead of adding a padding)

Answer (score 16):

Use a pseudo-element to increase  the "hit area"

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.star {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1);
  display: block;
  transition: 0.25s ease-in background-color, 0.25s ease-in opacity, 0.25s ease-out transform;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.star::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 500%;
  height: 500%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index:-1;
  border:1px solid green; /* for demo purposes */
  
}

.star:hover {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="star"></div>
```

Comment: Not `:before` but `::before` as it is pseudo-element, not a pseudo-class

Comment: I'm old school...both syntaxes are supported but OK.

Comment: Actually for IE8 `::before` is not supported

Comment: I avoid the double :: at all costs since it's only confusing and required nowhere(input placeholder text is an exception currently).

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Yeah...but then it's IE8....and who cares. :)

Comment: Still has 1.18% browser usage :P

Answer (score 1):

Your transparent border method is fine and works the best in all browsers ;)
Just add:

```
background-clip: padding-box;
```

To make sure the background does not show under the borders.

Answer (score 0):

Add circle under each star and give it a black background ex;

```
<div class="starWrapper">
    <div class="star"></div>
</div>

.star {  top:3px;
      left:3px;
      width: 5px;
      height: 5px;
      background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 50%;
      transform: scale(1);
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;}

 .startWrapper{
         position:absolute;
         background:#000;
         width:8px;
         height:8px;
         border-radius: 50%;}
```

Comment: number of stars seen with the unaided eye is around 5,000, your solution will double needed number of DOM elements. I don't think browsers will be happy with that.

Comment: the pseudo-element method does this this at really low-cost ;)

Comment: The question doesn't mention the number of stars and as @GCyrillus said pseudo-element can solve the issue at low-cost.